# Menu direito em cada row de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html, context-menu

Tenho uma tabela e estou tentando criar um menu de ação ao clicar botão direito em cada row da tabela.

Está funcionando parcialmente o problema que não consigo fazer o script selecionar o menu de contexto para cada linha ele está pegando sempre o último.

Criei um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t9e19rp/) para facilitar os testes do script e vou postar o código abaixo também:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .skills {
        background: #A6A6A5;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").contextmenu({
            delegate: "tbody tr",
            menu: ".table tbody tr .skills:first-child"
        });
    });
</script>

<h1>Shao Kan Game World</h1>

<!-- Os dados na tabela são ficticios e nao tem intencao de insultar os personagens -->

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Personagem</th>
            <th>Poder</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Luke</td>
            <td>Espadinha</td>
            <td class="skills">
                <ul class="skills" style="display: none; z-index: 4000;">
                    <li>SABRE DE LUZ</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Robocop</td>
            <td>Metralhadora</td>
            <td class="skills">
                <ul class="skills" style="display: none; z-index: 4000;">
                    <li>BAZUCAAAA</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

O que preciso é ao clicar sobre o `Robocop` ele exibir a UL que contém `Bazuca` e ao clicar sobre o `Luke` ele exibir o `Sabre de Luz`.

Comment: vlw pela edição @brasofilo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o [exemplo do @Peoplee](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30043/menu-direito-em-cada-row-de-uma-tabela/30051#30051), adaptei para automatizar o processo assim:

```
$('td.ativar').each(function(){
    $(this).contextmenu({
        menu: $(this).next().next().children('ul') // podemos usar jQuery aqui
    });
});
```

Coloquei a classe `ativar` nos `<td>`'s *Luke* e *Robocop*, e o menu vai ser definido através de um objeto jQuery usando o `<ul>` filho do segundo `next(td)`.

Obs.: a classe `skills` está sendo usado no `<td>` e no `<ul>` e isso parece problemático. Removi do `<td>` no meu exemplo.

```js
$('td.ativar').each(function(){
  $(this).contextmenu({
    menu: $(this).next().next().children('ul')
  });
});
```

```css
.skills {
    background: #A6A600;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/jquery.ui-contextmenu.js"></script>
    
  <h1>Shao Kan Game World</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Personagem</th>
            <th>Poder</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='ativar'>Luke</td>
            <td>Espadinha</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="skills" style="display: none; z-index: 4000;">
                    <li>SABRE DE LUZ</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='ativar'>Robocop</td>
            <td>Metralhadora</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="skills" style="display: none; z-index: 4000;">
                    <li>BAZUCAAAA</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Poderia colocar `$(this).parent().find('ul.skills');` para ser mais automatizado, pois assim se adicionar mais colunas (`td`) não será necessário atualizar o _Javascript_.

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode usar a mesma configuração para definir dois menus diferentes, você terá que criar um para cada menu diferente.

Isso ocorre porque o contextmenu usa um seletor para definir qual menu será usado, e não tem como você diferenciar qual menu será usado em um seletor. [Veja no código do plugin: jquery.ui-contextmenu.js linha 124](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/blob/master/jquery.ui-contextmenu.js#L124)

Uma solução rápida seria essa: http://jsfiddle.net/0t9e19rp/2/

Answer (score 2):

Melhorando a resposta do @brasofilo, o processo não precisa de classes adicionais além da classe `.table-context` na tabela (resposta Peoplee) e por linha, pegando sempre a última coluna como menu de contexto (resposta Brasofilo).

```
$(".table-context tbody tr").each(function() {
    var element = $(this);

    element.contextmenu({
       menu: element.children("td:last").children("ul")
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito, sabia que tinha jeito de simplificar :)

Answer (score -1):

Simplesmente remova `:first-child` em `menu`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").contextmenu({
        delegate: "tbody tr",
        menu: ".table tbody tr .skills"
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/0t9e19rp/1/)

Comment: Não da certo, fica 1 sobre o outro já tentei também!